# Including pictures into CSS behind Spring Security

Tags: java, html, css, spring, web-inf

I am new to Java programming and I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.  I am attempting to reference a picture from my picture directory to a css file but it's not pulling up the picture and only displaying the css.

I have amended my WebSecurityConfig to look like this:

```
@Override

protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .antMatchers("/", "/index", "/quiz/*", "/frontEndFiles/*", "/frontEndFiles/css/*", "/frontEndFiles/pictures/*", "/frontEndFiles/pictures/Yellowstone_Elk.jpg").permitAll()
```

I have also changed my application.properties to look like this:

```
 spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/frontEndFiles/**
 spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/META-INF/resources/frontEndFiles/
```

My file paths look like this for my WEB-INF and for my frontEndFiles which are at the same level after my resources directory:

- src

  - main

    - java

      - quizEngine

        - controllers
        - entities
        - Application
        - WebSecurityConfig
    - resources

      - META-INF

        - resources

          - frontEndFiles

            - css
            - pictures
          - WEB-INF

            - jsp (files)
        - application.properties

This is my jsp link for the css file which is located in the :

```
<link href="/frontEndFiles/css/quizEngineStartForm.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

And this is my /css/quizEngineStartForm.css referencing my jpg:

```
body  {
    background: url("/META-INF/resources/frontEndFiles/pictures/Yellowstone_Elk.jpg") no-repeat fixed;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

** note if I remove the /META-INF/resources from the url it errors out with 'cannot resolve directory frontEndFiles' **

Again, my html/css code from (/css/quizEngineStartForm.css) is being displayed but the picture does not show.  This has to either deal with permissions via the WebSecurityConfig, the ApplicationSettings, or an incorrect pathway.  If I use just a url to the web, it displays the picture.

Comment: Putting all your static resources in a folder named `static` with subfolders for css etc (`resources/static/css`) would be the typical way to do it. Then add matchers like `"/img/**", "/css/**", "/js/**",`.

Comment: What? Was that comment supposed to be addressed to @ChiefTwoPencils? Because I really have no clue about this; I was only here to make an edit.

Comment: @ Laurel, you are correct.  My bad.

Comment: I was able to figure it out.  In IntelliJ the internal project url of "/frontEndFiles/pictures/Yellowstone_Elk.jpg" indicates an incomplete path and indicates errors but trying just that link works and it links to the picture.